# Ajax form submit is multiplying content

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I have an ajax function that, before sending, does something like this:

```
function prepareGalleries() {
    if($('.galleryField').length) {
        $('.galleryField').val('');
        $('.galleryField').each(function() {
            var images = '';
            var galleryField = $(this).attr('name');
            $('#' + galleryField + ' li').each(function() {
                images += $('img', this).attr('data-src') + ';';
            })
            images = images.replace(/;+$/, "");
            $(this).val(images);
         })
    }
}

function saveFields(form) {
    prepareGalleries();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: $("#" + form).serialize(),
      success: function(data)
      {
           window.location.reload();
      }
     });
 }
```

It looks for hidden .galleryField inputs and then for each one of them gets the images in the matching galleryBox (with id same as galleryField's name).

It then takes each image data-src value and adds it to a string, which it puts in the galleryField inputs.

This works, but on each save it duplicates itself - so first save I might have two images, **then saving again (without adding more images) 4, then 8 etc etc**...

In my php I have something sort of like this:

```
checkAction();
function checkAction()
{
   if ( $_POST['action'] === 'save' ) {
       saveAction();
   }
}

function saveAction()
{
    if ( $_POST['form'] === 'page' ) {
        foreach ( $_POST as $item => $value ) {
            if ( $item != 'currentPage' && $item != 'form' && $item != 'action')      
            {
                save( 'pages', $GLOBALS['currentPage'], $item, $value );
            }
        }
     } else {
        foreach ( $_POST as $item => $value ) {
            if ( $item != 'form' && $item != 'action' ) {
                save( $_POST['form'], $item, $value );
            }
        }
    }
}

function save()
{
    if ( !$GLOBALS['loggedIn'] )
        return;
    $numArgs = func_num_args();
    $args    = func_get_args();
    switch ( $numArgs ) {
        case 2:
            $GLOBALS['db'][$args[0]] = $args[1];
            break;
        case 3:
            $GLOBALS['db'][$args[0]][$args[1]] = $args[2];
            break;
        case 4:
            $GLOBALS['db'][$args[0]][$args[1]][$args[2]] = $args[3];
            break;
     }
    file_put_contents( 'database.js', json_encode( $GLOBALS['db'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );
}
```

So it seems to either be appending to the value or my images loop is a bit broken.

I am at a loose end with this one...have been scratching my head for hours. Have tried everything I could think of.

The above ajax and php works for other fields - just not this gallery field...which is what I find so perplexing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but isn't `$('.galleryField[name="' + galleryField + '"]')` the same as `$(this)`, since `galleryField` is `$(this).attr('name')`.

Comment: Since Javascript data doesn't persist across reloads, the only thing I can think if is that the code being run on the server when you make the AJAX call is duplicating it.

Comment: Good point...will change that...thanks. :-) If only that was the only problem.